# Breaking line in <td>

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm displaying a table from my database to my view.

```
@model IEnumerable<test1.Models.Malfunction>
@{ 
ViewBag.Title = "Malfunctions";
}

<h2>Malfunctions</h2>

<table id="customers" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Date Reported</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Movie</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var malfunction in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@malfunction.Id</td>
            <td>@malfunction.ReportDescription</td>
            <td>@malfunction.DateReported</td>
            <td>@malfunction.Customer</td>
            <td>@malfunction.Movie</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

This property:

```
<td>@malfunction.ReportDescription</td>
```

can contain a big amount of text which if too long will overlap the next property in line which is:

```
<td>@malfunction.DateReported</td>
```

What I want to do is break the line after the width of the cell is reached so it doesn't overlap with the text in DateReported.

Comment: you can use any front-end framework or <br> tag to next line the element.

Comment: use `word-break: break-all;` to break the line.

Comment: @Justcode Where to add that? <td style = 'word-break: break-all;'>, doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add:

```
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/hezerubufa/edit?css,output)

Comment: Where to add that? <td style = 'word-break: break-all;'>, doesn't work

Comment: Add it into your CSS. See my link at bottom of the answer. You can see it working.